# Application.Match() always returns 91 from VBA fx, BUT

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

When I call `Application.Match()` from Immediate Window, it works. From module in VBA, it returns "91 Obj Var or with block not set" error.

I tried match from worksheet, works fine. I've tried changing the "array" arg to "category" (named range, workbook scope), "errCodes!B25:B295", range("category"), range("errCodes!B25:B295")... I've looked at other error 91's and they are not relevant to match.

```
Function findCD(prevRng As Range)
    Dim oldCDrng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nextCD As Integer

    Dim oldC, oldD, newC, newD, oldCD, newCD As String
    On Error GoTo err_hand
    'Argument is always above cell

    '1 find prev cell value
    oldCD = WorksheetFunction.Index(prevRng, 0)
    oldC = Mid(oldCD, 1, 1)
    oldD = Mid(oldCD, 2, 1)

    '2 find next C & D where different
    'find current CD
    oldCDrng = Application.Match("02", Range("category"), 0)

    'next CD is at least CD + 1
    'verify this
    nextCD = oldCD + 1

    nextCDrng = Application.Match(nextCD, Range("errorCodes!D22:D295"), 0)

    '3 return this value

    Exit Function
err_hand:

    findCD = "ERROR!" & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")"    
End Function
```

Comment: How do you call this function and which line causes the error?

Comment: I called it from the same workbook sheet "errCodeDesc" cell B8. ... the line "oldCDrng = Application.Match("02", Range("category"), 0)" throws the error 91. The same exact thing from immediate window returns "11" - correct.

Comment: Are you aware that with the declaration `Dim oldC, oldD, newC, newD, oldCD, newCD As String` only `newCD` will be a string and the other variables will be variants? You need to type each variable with an `as`.  `nextCD` is a number but oldCD has been assigned a range. Now you add a number to a range?. `prevRng` is a range and an Index of that will return a range but Index zero does not exist. Then you add 1 to a non existing range and try to use that as the numerical argument in a Match?? This code cannot possibly work. Use Option Explicit to iron out the most glaring errors.

Comment: Or, if `prevRng` is a once cell range, why use Index?

Comment: The range `oldCDrng` is not assigned when you try to set its value from `Match`